# In ZFC, does every strucutre have an ultrapower that is universal?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, filters

I call a structure $M$ of cardinality $\kappa$ *universal* if it is $\kappa^+$-universal, i.e., there is an elementary embedding from any $N \equiv M$ to $M$ if $|N| \le \kappa$.  (I think this is a reasonable definition, which is also used by the textbook by Marker.)

Under GCH, any structure has a saturated ultrapower, which is a fortiori universal.

Of course, there is a structure with no elementary extension that is saturated in some model of ZFC.  On the other hand, it is a theorem of ZFC that any structure has an elementary extension that is universal (this is a special model construction).

My question is whether ZFC implies that every structure have an ultrapower that is universal.

I believe that this is easy to do with the union of a chain of ultrapowers (an ultralimit?), but that is the extent I know.